# VB.NET Cancel execution of a long running, blocking method within a Task?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task, cancellation

I am trying to cancel a task which contains a long running, blocking method call.  My problem is that execution does not return to the caller until the long running operation is completed.  (Even if it has been cancelled.)

```
Public Class DebugForm
    Private Sub DebugForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
        Dim cts As New CancellationTokenSource
        Task.Run(Sub()
                     DoLongRunningBlockingWork()
                     cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                 End Sub, cts.Token)
        'Simulate cancelling after a second.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        cts.Cancel()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoLongRunningBlockingWork()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)
        Debug.WriteLine("Completed")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to check the status of long-running process on that staus you will able to return to the caller.
Each process consists of the stack associated with the process, and stack consists of the status variable by which you will able to see the status of the process.